# rijndael decrypting file "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid"

Tags: c#, encryption

I tried to build a simple De/En-cryption class for files based on rijndael with CBC. The encryption works like a charm, but when I try to read the data it always gives me "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid". Most of the Questions on Stackoverflow gets answered with "You forgot to flush the final block" or use the right padding while decrypting or encrypting, which is mostly the solution, but not in my case. (I hope).

```
    public int BlockSize { get; set; } = 128;
    public int IVSize { get; set; } = 256;

public Stream Decrypt(KeyPair pair, string file)
    {
        if (pair?.IV == null || pair.Key == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Key missing");
        }

        var returningStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var myRij = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            myRij.IV = pair.IV;
            myRij.Key = pair.Key;
            myRij.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            myRij.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            var decrypt = myRij.CreateDecryptor();

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, decrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[64];
                var read = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                while (read > 0)
                {
                    returningStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    // I think the last Iteration is failing... 
                    // Also cryptoStream.CopyTo(returningStream) throws the exception
                    read = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        returningStream.Position = 0;
        return returningStream;
    }

    public KeyPair Encrypt(string file, string outfile)
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
        { 
            // Generate new IV and KEY
            myRijndael.KeySize = IVSize;
            myRijndael.BlockSize = BlockSize;
            myRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            myRijndael.GenerateIV();
            myRijndael.GenerateKey();

            var encrypter = myRijndael.CreateEncryptor();

            // Create memoryspace for crypto
            using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Create cryptostream
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memory, encrypter, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    // read file to encrypt
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        // copy content to cryptostream
                        var buffer = new byte[64];
                        var read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        while (read > 0)
                        {
                            cryptoStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                            read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        }
                        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    }

                    using (var encryptedFile = new FileStream(outfile, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        // Reset the stream position for reading
                        memory.Position = 0;

                        // read and copy content to file
                        memory.CopyTo(encryptedFile);
                    }                         
                }
            }

            return new KeyPair {IV = myRijndael.IV, Key = myRijndael.Key};
        }
    }
```

I gracefully accept every solution or optimization on my code.

Comment: Maybe the encryption doesn't really work like a charm... Have you tried encrypting or decrypting your file with other software? You could encrypt with Software X, then let your code decrypt, or vice versa, to verify where it goes wrong.

Comment: Your code seems to work when encrypting then decrypting a file, passing the `KeyPair` returned from `Encrypt()` immediately to `Decrypt()`. That suggests that in your tests, the decryption method isn't using the same key/IV as was used to initially encrypt the data.